# How to diagnose Newtonsoft deserializer returning an empty object and no errors

Tags: c#, error-handling, json.net, json-deserialization

Deserializing a JSON result from an API call, I first created the data class using something like Json2cSharp.com.  I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.

```
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
DataClass.PurchaseOrderResponse data = new DataClass.PurchaseOrderResponse();
data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataClass.PurchaseOrderResponse>(content);
```

`DeserializeObject` returns no "data" and no errors or exceptions.

I can view the "content" returned from the API call in Visual Studios' built in JSON viewer, and other online JSON viewers and the content appears to be okay.

Is there a way to probe into what Newtonsoft might be finding wrong with the JsonConvert routine?

(P.S. I'm using this method for a previous API call and it is deserializing that content just fine)

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "Item": [
    {
      "EmailSentCount": 0,
      "DisableInventoryCount": false,
      "POType": 0,
      "CancelledPOID": 0,
      "TotalBalance": 8610.8,
      "TotalBalanceNotReceivedGood": 0.0,
      "VendorID": 13297,
      "PurchaseTitle": "",
      "CreatedOn": "2021-03-02T15:47:21.757",
      "CreatedBy": 75432,
      "OrderTotal": 0.0,
      "TaxTotal": 0.0,
      "ShippingTotal": 0.0,
      "GrandTotal": 8610.8,
      "DateOrdered": "2021-03-02T15:47:21.763",
      "LastRevisedOn": "2021-03-17T18:14:39.653",
      "RevisedBy": 104593,
      "PurchaseOrderStatus": 3,
      "PaymentStatus": 10,
      "ExtraCharges": 0.0,
      "TotalRefunded": 0.0,
      "PurchaseOrdersShippingStatus": 2,
      "TrackingNumber": "",
      "TrackingNumbers": [
        {
          "ShippedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "ShippingCarrier": "",
          "TrackingNumber": ""
        }
      ],
      "ShippedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "CourierService": "",
      "PurchaseOrdersPriority": 0,
      "ReceivingStatus": 2,
      "CompanyID": 163,
      "PurchaseOrdersApproved": true,
      "DropShipOrderNumber": 0,
      "VendorInvoiceNumber": "21-6043-1",
      "VendorInvoiceFileName": "",
      "VendorInvoiceFileNameOriginal": "",
      "Invoices": [
        {
          "InvoiceNumber": "21-6043-1"
        }
      ],
      "Memo": "",
      "ExpectedDeliveryDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "DiscountTotal": 0.0,
      "bExported": false,
      "DisplayName": "Azomite Soil Products, LLC",
      "CM": 0,
      "NotesCount": 0,
      "PaidOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "UnitCounts": 950,
      "PurchaseOrderCreditMemo": false,
      "WarehouseID": 109,
      "Items": [
        {
          "ID": 4162,
          "SKU": "Azomite-44",
          "VendorSKU": "",
          "ProductName": "Azomite Micronized Bag, 44 lb  Organic Trace Mineral Powder-67 Essential Minerals for You & Your Garden Bag",
          "QtyOrdered": 950,
          "QtyReceived": 950,
          "UnitPrice": 9.064,
          "AdjustedPrice": 9.064,
          "LineTotal": 8610.8,
          "ExpectedDeliveryDate": null
        }
      ],
      "RequestedShippingCarrier": "",
      "RequestedShippingService": "",
      "ShipToAddress": {
        "IsShippingAddress": false,
        "IsBillingAddress": false,
        "AddressClassification": 0,
        "Notes": "",
        "HomePhone": "",
        "EmailAddress": "",
        "AddressStatus": 1,
        "AddressSource": 17,
        "ID": -1,
        "FirstName": "Joe",
        "MiddleInitial": "",
        "LastName": "Toohey",
        "CompanyName": "EasyGo Products Irvine",
        "StreetLine1": "16661 Jamboree Rd.",
        "StreetLine2": "",
        "City": "Irvine",
        "StateName": "CA",
        "StateCode": "CA",
        "PostalCode": "92606",
        "CountryName": "",
        "CountryCode": "US",
        "PhoneNumber": "949-586-8470",
        "FaxNumber": "",
        "WebSiteURL": ""
      },
      "ID": 1428
    },
    {
      "EmailSentCount": 0,
      "DisableInventoryCount": false,
      "POType": 0,
      "CancelledPOID": 0,
      "TotalBalance": 952.0,
      "TotalBalanceNotReceivedGood": 0.0,
      "VendorID": 13295,
      "PurchaseTitle": "",
      "CreatedOn": "2021-03-02T12:56:37.643",
      "CreatedBy": 75432,
      "OrderTotal": 0.0,
      "TaxTotal": 0.0,
      "ShippingTotal": 0.0,
      "GrandTotal": 952.0,
      "DateOrdered": "2021-03-02T12:56:37.663",
      "LastRevisedOn": "2021-03-05T14:38:25.91",
      "RevisedBy": 104593,
      "PurchaseOrderStatus": 3,
      "PaymentStatus": 10,
      "ExtraCharges": 0.0,
      "TotalRefunded": 0.0,
      "PurchaseOrdersShippingStatus": 2,
      "TrackingNumber": "",
      "TrackingNumbers": [
        {
          "ShippedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "ShippingCarrier": "",
          "TrackingNumber": ""
        }
      ],
      "ShippedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "CourierService": "",
      "PurchaseOrdersPriority": 0,
      "ReceivingStatus": 2,
      "CompanyID": 163,
      "PurchaseOrdersApproved": true,
      "DropShipOrderNumber": 0,
      "VendorInvoiceNumber": "61351",
      "VendorInvoiceFileName": "",
      "VendorInvoiceFileNameOriginal": "",
      "Invoices": [
        {
          "InvoiceNumber": "61351"
        }
      ],
      "Memo": "",
      "ExpectedDeliveryDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "DiscountTotal": 0.0,
      "bExported": false,
      "DisplayName": "Lowes",
      "CM": 0,
      "NotesCount": 0,
      "PaidOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "UnitCounts": 280,
      "PurchaseOrderCreditMemo": false,
      "WarehouseID": 109,
      "Items": [
        {
          "ID": 4161,
          "SKU": "Quikrete-50",
          "VendorSKU": "",
          "ProductName": "Quikrete Play Sand - 50",
          "QtyOrdered": 280,
          "QtyReceived": 280,
          "UnitPrice": 3.4,
          "AdjustedPrice": 3.4,
          "LineTotal": 952.0,
          "ExpectedDeliveryDate": null
        }
      ],
      "RequestedShippingCarrier": "",
      "RequestedShippingService": "",
      "ShipToAddress": {
        "IsShippingAddress": false,
        "IsBillingAddress": false,
        "AddressClassification": 0,
        "Notes": "",
        "HomePhone": "",
        "EmailAddress": "",
        "AddressStatus": 1,
        "AddressSource": 17,
        "ID": -1,
        "FirstName": "Joe",
        "MiddleInitial": "",
        "LastName": "Toohey",
        "CompanyName": "EasyGo Products Irvine",
        "StreetLine1": "16661 Jamboree Rd.",
        "StreetLine2": "",
        "City": "Irvine",
        "StateName": "CA",
        "StateCode": "CA",
        "PostalCode": "92606",
        "CountryName": "",
        "CountryCode": "US",
        "PhoneNumber": "949-586-8470",
        "FaxNumber": "",
        "WebSiteURL": ""
      },
      "ID": 1427
    }
  ],
  "TotalResults": 2
}
```

Comment: Share your json string and your model please.

Comment: I can't post the JSON string returned by the API. It's toooo long.

Comment: If Newtonsoft can't "deserialize" some data, is there not some way to trap what it found that it could not do?

Comment: There is some ways, but first I need your model structure

Answer (score 2):

By default Json.Net does not complain if the JSON does not exactly line up with a class model.  Most problems having to do with getting no data are due to having the model not match up to the JSON in some way.  For example the names might be spelled differently, or the properties are not defined at the right level.

You can change the default behavior in the `JsonSerializerSettings` by setting `MissingMemberHandling` to `Error` instead of `Ignore`.  This tells the serializer to throw an exception whenever there is a property in the JSON for which there is no matching property in the model.  Also, you can set an error handler in the settings which will allow you to catch the error and continue on if you want.  That way you can get a list of all the errors in one go.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
    Error = (sender, eventArgs) => {
        Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.ErrorContext.Error.Message);  // or write to a log
        eventArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
};
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PurchaseOrderResponse>(content, settings);
```

Here's a demo of deserializing your JSON into an almost completely empty class structure with the above settings enabled:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/9wJ0tu

Comment: Brian Thanks for the editing. Reads nicer.  And BIG thanks for the MissingMemberHandling code.  This did the job!!!  I'm able to let the vendor know what is wrong with their API results.  I found several other errors in their API returns.  Now it's in their hands to correct. Again. Thanks

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Resolved:

The sample JSON return values, when put thru Json2csharp converter (or the others), returns the public class:

```
            public class Root
        {
            public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
            public int TotalResults { get; set; }
        }
```

The call to deseriazeObject needed a .Root as in:

```
var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataClass.PurchaseOrderResponse.Root>(content, settings);
```

Now all is happy and content.  Thank you to all who helped out in my education.